# Text is shifted to the right beyond the margin

Tags: margins, texlive, texmaker

I don't know what's happened but until today everything was fine with my document. Today I've added a couple of lines, then I've compiled the document and **all** the text has been shifted to the right beyond the margin. How can I solve the problem?

I am using Texmaker with TeX Live. Actually, in the past, when everything was OK with Texmaker, I've tried to upload this document on Overleaf and the compilation there gave me this same problem.

In the image you see the babel package is commented out but was just for a test. I have the same problem with or without it. 
[image]

`main.tex` file

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{report}

\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}            
\usepackage{rotating}    
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[scriptsize]{caption} 
\usepackage[italian,english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\hyphenation{a-gen-tiz-za-zio-ne}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\setlength{\paperwidth}{16cm}
\setlength{\paperheight}{24cm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{2cm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{2cm}
\setlength\headheight{13.6pt}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.4cm}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-0.4cm}
\linespread{1.1}

\renewcommand{\captionfont}{\normalfont \sffamily \itshape \small}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document} 

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\listoftables

\cleardoublepage
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptername\ \thechapter.\ #1}{}} 
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ #1}}   

\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}                                    
\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\leftmark}    
\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\rightmark}     
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.3pt} 

\pagestyle{fancy}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\import{chapters/}{chapter01.tex}
\clearpage{\thispagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}

\end{document}
```

`chapter01.tex` file. Please create a `chapters` folder and place inside it this file.

```
\chapter{Introduction}
\label{chapter01}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{quotation}
{\footnotesize
\noindent{\emph{``Terence: Rotta a nord con circospezione \\
Bud: Ehi, gli ordini li do io qui!\\
Terence: Ok, comante\\
Bud: Rotta a nord\\
Terence: Soltanto?\\
Bud: Con circospezione!''}
}
\begin{flushright}
Chi Trova un Amico Trova un Tesoro
\end{flushright}
}
\end{quotation}
\vspace{0.5cm}

\noindent L'introduzione deve essere atomica, quindi non deve contenere ne sottosezioni ne paragrafi ne altro. Il titolo, il sommario e l'introduzione devono sembrare delle scatole cinesi, nel senso che lette in quest'ordine devono progressivamente svelare informazioni sul contenuto per incatenare l'attenzione del lettore e indurlo a leggere l'opera fino in fondo. L'introduzione deve essere tripartita, non graficamente ma logicamente:

\section{Inquadramento generale}
La prima parte contiene una frase che spiega l'area generale dove si svolge il lavoro; una che spiega la sottoarea piu specifica dove si svolge il lavoro e la terza, che dovrebbe cominciare con le seguenti parole ``lo scopo della tesi \`e \dots'', illustra l'obbiettivo del lavoro. Poi vi devono essere una o due frasi che contengano una breve spiegazione di cosa e come e stato fatto, delle attivit\`a  sperimentali, dei risultati ottenuti con una valutazione e degli sviluppi futuri. La prima parte deve essere circa una facciata e mezza o due

\section{Breve descrizione del lavoro}
La seconda parte deve essere una esplosione della prima e deve quindi mostrare in maniera piu esplicita l'area dove si svolge il lavoro, le fonti bibliografiche piu importanti su cui si fonda il lavoro in maniera sintetica (una pagina) evidenziando i lavori in letteratura che presentano attinenza con il lavoro affrontato in modo da mostrare da dove e perche e sorta la tematica di studio. Poi si mostrano esplicitamente le realizzazioni, le direttive future di ricerca, quali sono i problemi aperti e quali quelli affrontati e si ripete lo scopo della tesi. Questa parte deve essere piena (ma non grondante come la sezione due) di citazioni bibliografiche e deve essere lunga circa 4 facciate.

\section{Struttura della tesi}
La terza parte contiene la descrizione della struttura della tesi ed \`e organizzata nel modo seguente.
``La tesi e strutturata nel modo seguente.

Nella sezione due si mostra \dots

Nella sez. tre si illustra \dots

Nella sez. quattro si descrive \dots

Nelle conclusioni si riassumono gli scopi, le valutazioni di questi e le prospettive future \dots

Nell'appendice A si riporta \dots (Dopo ogni sezione o appendice ci vuole un punto).''

I titoli delle sezioni da 2 a M-1 sono indicativi, ma bisogna cercare di mantenere un significato equipollente nel caso si vogliano cambiare. Queste sezioni possono contenere eventuali sottosezioni.
```

Comment: Please do not add a code snippet as a screenshot only, but create a minimal working example (MWE) reproducing this issue and add this code as text to the question. (The two lines reported are not really errors, but rather warnings.)

Comment: The issue is that the text is completely shifted to the right, that's all. No compilation errors.

Comment: How can you have both `\paperwidth` set to 16 cm and an  A4 paper format? Same question for `\paperheight`.

Comment: Also `\oddsidemargin=2cm` means the real left margin is 2cm + 1in. Modifying the page layout is much easier with package `geometry`.

Comment: I don't know Bernard. I am using a document format written by someone else. Could you please explain how to solve the discrepancy?

Comment: I can, but please post a minimal example (compilable) code reproducing your problem.

Comment: Oh! b.t.w., welcome to TeX SX!

Comment: OK, I've added a code snippet that should reproduce the problem. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Which paper size do you want to use? 16×24 cm or 21×29.7cm? And which real margins do you want to have?

Comment: I must use the standard A4 format, that is, 210 × 297 mm. As for the margins let's say 2cm. I am writing a thesis. I don't know if there's a commonly used margin size. If there's not let's stick to those 2cm as in the template I've found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very simple with package `geometry`.

*Unrelated*: `subfigure` is obsolete and no more maintained. It's better to use `subcaption` and its eponymous environment.. Also, don't forget to load the `T1` font encoding since italian has accented letters. Last, for your quoting at the beginning of chapter 1, I suggest you take a look at the possibilities of the `epigraph` package.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[showframe, hmargin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[italian,english]{babel}
\hyphenation{a-gen-tiz-za-zio-ne}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[scriptsize]{caption}
\renewcommand{\captionfont}{\normalfont \sffamily \itshape \small}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%
\linespread{1.1}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

%\import{}{dedication.tex}
%\cleardoublepage \pagenumbering{Roman}
%\import{}{abstract.tex}
%\cleardoublepage
%\import{}{sommario.tex}
%\cleardoublepage
%\import{}{ringraziamenti.tex}
%\cleardoublepage

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\listoftables

\cleardoublepage
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptername\ \thechapter.\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ #1}}

\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\rightmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.3pt}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\import{chapters/}{chapter01.tex}
\clearpage{\thispagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}

\end{document}
```

[image]